# Android xml design slowing down my application

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout

I have a layout design in my app.

It works smooth on emulator but when I open the App on a real device and scroll it, it scrolls rough I mean not smooth, too slow.

(I used android:largeHeap="true" otherwise it didn't work on my device but only on emulator.)

Can you help me to make it move smoothly?

[Picture of xml design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl22f.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <GridLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:rowCount="6"
    android:columnCount="2">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardElevation="6dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout

                android:id="@+id/animal_layout"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/elephant"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Animals"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#6f6f6f"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        >
        
        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/art_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                 <ImageView
                     android:src="@drawable/art"
                     android:layout_width="80dp"
                     android:layout_height="80dp"/>
                 <TextView
                     android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="Art"
                     android:textSize="18sp"
                     android:textColor="#6f6f6f"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/biography_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/biography"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Biography"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#6f6f6f"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/countries_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/countries"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Countries"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#6f6f6f"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/culture_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/culture"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Culture"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#6f6f6f"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/environment_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/environment"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Environment"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#6f6f6f"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/health_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/health"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Health"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#6f6f6f"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/holidays_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/holidays"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Holidays"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#6f6f6f"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/literature_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/literature"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Literature"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#6f6f6f"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/politics_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/politics"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Politics"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#6f6f6f"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/science_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/science"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Science"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#6f6f6f"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/sports_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/sport"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sports"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#6f6f6f"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by decreasing sizes of pictures in imageView.

Answer (score 0):

Each widget and layout you add to your application requires initialization, layout, and drawing. For example, using nested instances of LinearLayout can lead to an excessively deep view hierarchy. Furthermore, nesting several instances of LinearLayout that use the layout_weight parameter can be especially expensive as each child needs to be measured twice. This is particularly important when the layout is inflated repeatedly, such as when used in a ListView or GridView.

Read here for Optimizing layout - https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout

**Solution -**

ConstraintLayout is the new way to achieve the same flat xml structure. It will surely improve your response time

You can read more about how Constraint Layout improve performance at

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used Constraint Layout with guidelines in my previous project and I can say that using Constraint layout was very easy and memory-friendly. In this case decreasing picture size worked but your opinion is right.

Comment: Thanks, I hope it helps + use svg instead of png as much as possible and if you find it helpful would you mind marking this answer correct or +1

Comment: it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." when my account activated, i will give you a point. Ty again.